# iOS - Set Detail Disclosure Button on MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, uibutton, mapkit, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I have the following method in my MapViewController:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation {
    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
    if (!annotationView) {
        annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"MapVC"];
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
        annotationView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
        // could put a rightCalloutAccessoryView here
    } else {
        annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        [(UIImageView *)annotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView setImage:nil];
    }

    return annotationView;
}
```

I believe it's properly set up, but when my map shows my annotations with title and subtitle properly, but they don't show the detail disclosure button, am I missing something?

Another thing is that when debugging this method is never called, yet the annotation view shows up with title and subtitle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Most likely the map view's `delegate` is not set.

If the `delegate` is not set or if you don't implement the `viewForAnnotation` method, the map view will create a default annotation view which is a red pin with a callout containing only the title and subtitle (unless the title is blank in which case you will get a pin but no callout).

Either connect the map view's `delegate` outlet to File's Owner or in code add this (eg. in `viewDidLoad` before the annotation is added):

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

Also, if you're not using ARC, add `autorelease` to the `alloc` lines to avoid a memory leak.